# SQL - Select items where value equals multiple values

Tags: sql, sqlite

Have a very hard time wording this question, but below is a table to illustrate my problem.

```
Id   itemID   categoryID
1      5         10
2      5         16
3      6         10
4      2         10
```

If I have a table setup like this, and I want to select "itemID" where categoryID equals 10 AND 16, the result should be itemID 5. A bit more context would be the user has a list of checkboxes that are the categoryID's, and if they select just categoryID 10, then itemID 5, 2 and 6 would appear. If they also select categoryID 16, then only itemID 5 would appear since it has category 10 and 16, where itemID 2 only has category 10.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE categoryID IN (10,16)` or `SELECT * FROM table WHERE categoryID IN (10)` have the content of `IN` dynamically inserted accordingly to the selections

Comment: @GeorgesBrisset sorry, but no. First query would return rows where categoryId is either 10 or 16 (all of them). Second one would return rows where categoryId is 10 (all but Id = 2)

Comment: @supertopi, thanks for the correction. I admit I did not try it and answered too fast. thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of a "set-within-sets" subquery.  I think the most general way to solve these is using aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select itemID
from t
group by itemId
having sum(case when categoryID = 10 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when categoryID = 16 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause is counting the number of rows that match one category.  You can easily see how this would generalize for more categories, or to exclude a category.  For instance, if you wants 10 and 16 but not 22:

```
select itemID
from t
group by itemId
having sum(case when categoryID = 10 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when categoryID = 16 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when categoryID = 22 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Join the table to itself:

```
select t1.itemID
from mytable t1
join mytable t2 on t2.itemID = t1.itemID
where t1.categoryID = 10
and t2.categoryID = 16;
```